# Speed Up AutoComplete Popup in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When typing a query into MySQL Workbench, the autocomplete suggestion popup is so slow. After typing a couple letters of a column or table name, I have to pause for about a second or more for the suggestion box to popup.

Is there anyway to make the suggestion box appear immediately as I'm typing rather than wait for a pause?

Answer (score 6):

This is on purpose to avoid that the popup comes up constantly while you are typing (the delay is 500ms atm, hard coded). However, by using the hot key you can always trigger code completion immediately (on OSX this is command + esc, otherwise control + space bar).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It works
If you have each schema open (dropped down) in the Navigator, the autocomplete will work.

Thanks

for more information refer to this link
[MySQL bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92015)

Thanks